# Average of an Unbounded sequence of postive numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Could someone check my proof.  More of a sketch really.

Can it happen that $s_n>0$ for all $n$ and that $\limsup s_n=\infty$, although $\lim\sigma_n=0$, where $\sigma_n={\sum_{k=1}^ns_n\over n+1}$.

Let $M>0$, $\{s_{n_k}\}$the subsequence such that $s_{n_k}<M$ for all $k$, $\{s_{m_k}\}$ the subsequence such that $s_{m_k}\ge M$ for all $k$.
Finally for each $n$, let $a(n)=\max\{k:s_{n_k}<n\}$ and $b(n)=\max\{k:s_{m_k}<n\}$. For $n$ large enough,

$$\begin{align}
\sigma_n & ={\sum_{k=0}^{a(n)}s_{n_k}\over n+1}+{\sum_{k=0}^{b(n)}s_{m_k}\over n+1}\\
& >{\sum_{k=0}^{b(n)}s_{m_k}\over n+1}\\
&\ge{(b(n)+1)M\over b(n)+1}=M.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n\ne 0.$$

Comment: True, but we are looking at $\limsup s_n$ and $\lim\sigma_n$. Two different sequences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears $\sigma_n$ is supposed to be the average of the first $n+1$ terms-you should state that. On the right you are using $n$ for the value used for separating the subsequences, so the first line is not correct.  Your definitions in the sentence starting "Finally" do not work.  It is possible that there are infinitely many $s_n \lt M$, so $a(n)$ is not defined.  We know there are infinitely many $s_n \gt M$.

Comment: This was a rough sketch. Let me try to make myself more clear. $a(n)=|\{k: k\le n, s_n<M\}|$ and $b(n)$ defined in a similar way for $s_n\ge M$.

Comment: From the second line to the third, you cannot replace $n$ by $b(n)$ in the denominator.  That reduces the denominator and increases the fraction.  Terms where $s_n \gt M$ could be very rare.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. I knew something was suspicious.

Answer (score -1):

Since the question ask can this happen, an example would suffice. Take $\{s_n\} = \log(\log(n+1))$ for $n\geq 2$.
Then
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\log(\log(n+1)) = \infty
$$
We can write $\sigma_n$ as 
$$
\sigma_n = \frac{\log(\log(3))+\log(\log(4))+\cdots + \log(\log(n+1))}{n+1}\leq\frac{\log(n\log(n))}{n+1}
$$
The limit of $\sigma_n$ is
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{n+1}\\
&\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n\log(n))}{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n+1}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(\log(n))}{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(\log(n))}{n+1}\\
&= 0
\end{align}
Therefore, it can happen that $s_n > 0$ and $\limsup s_n=\infty$ although $\lim\sigma_n = 0$.